# jquery mobile dialog window close returns to a blank page

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, dialog

I have a small app the returns search results via PHP and MySQL.  These search results create a list of buttons that the user will then tap to select.  This in turn launches a dialog (via data-rel="dialog") with a set of choices.  When the cancel/close function is selected the dialog is closed but the search results page is blank.  I am using this to cancel the dialog:

Cancel

To be clear each page is different file.  so I have search.php, list.php, and detail.php.  I have tried to disable ajax on the links to no avail.  Each time the cancel or close dialog button is clicked the list.php is blank.  I am guessing this has something to do with jQuery wiping out the DOM.  Is there anyway around this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, same setup as you.  I'm doing a search to the server, which returns a result set, that result set is loaded into a listview, then the user can select an item in the list view and a dialog appears, if I click cancel, sometimes it will return to the resultset of the search, sometimes it returns back to the page and the listview is cleared and the search needs to be done again.  Did you come up with a solution or know why this behavior is happening?  I'm using RC2 jQuery Mobile.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug by opening the search result page directly in browser. 
eg.,  http://localhost/list.php#/search.php?q=keywordyousearch to http://localhost/search.php?q=keywordyousearch

Normally jQuery Mobile shows blank page if there is an error in page while loading via Ajax.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I am not receiving a blank page.  My content div is blank.  I assumed that a dialog would operate much like a dialog in jQuery ui.  Apparently that is not the case.  Once the dialog is opened the content div on the list.php page is empty.